# Java is requiring sentinel value from two separate inputs

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, sentinel

I've just come across sentinel controlled iteration and I'm having some difficulties. I have to make a program that obtains the mileage and gallons used from the user, calculates the total mpg. I am trying to use -1 as a sentinel value to exit the loop when the user has finished, but when I go to enter the value, Java doesn't terminate the program. Instead it asks for another value from gallons. How do I get it to accept the sentinel value from the first input?

Example:

Enter miles or -1 to exit

-1

Enter gallons

-1

Terminate

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activity3_17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // processing phase
        int miles = 1;
        int gallons = 1;
        int totalMiles = 0;
        int totalGallons = 0;
        float mpg = 0;


        System.out.println("Enter miles or -1 to exit");
        miles = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter gallons");
        gallons = input.nextInt();

        while (miles != -1) {
            System.out.println("Enter miles or -1 to exit");
            miles = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter gallons or -1 to exit");
            gallons = input.nextInt();

            totalMiles = totalMiles + miles;
            totalGallons = totalGallons + gallons;


        }
        if (miles == -1) {
            System.out.print("Terminate");
        }
        else{
            mpg = (float) totalMiles / totalGallons;
            System.out.println(mpg);
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the user can enter `-1` on the gallons, but you don't check the value of that variable for that exit condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the user entered -1 inside the `while` loop. If they did, exit the loop using `break` and then terminate the program.

`mpg` is still printed within the loop, but only after the check is made. This ensures that the user gave valid input.

I decided to make the loop condition `true` since the loop should break if `miles` *or* `gallons` is -1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int miles = 1;
    int gallons = 1;
    int totalMiles = 0;
    int totalGallons = 0;
    float mpg = 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter miles or -1 to exit");
        miles = input.nextInt();
        if (miles == -1) break;

        System.out.println("Enter gallons or -1 to exit");
        gallons = input.nextInt();
        if (gallons == -1) break;

        totalMiles = totalMiles + miles;
        totalGallons = totalGallons + gallons;
        mpg = (float) totalMiles / totalGallons;

        System.out.println(mpg);
    }
    input.close();
    System.out.print("Terminate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java only evaluates the `while` loop every time it completes. Therefore, you will need to manually check whether or not `miles` was -1 and break the loop.

```
while (miles != -1) {
    System.out.println("Enter miles or -1 to exit");
    miles = input.nextInt();

    if (miles == -1) break;         

    System.out.println("Enter gallons or -1 to exit");
    gallons = input.nextInt();

    totalMiles = totalMiles + miles;
    totalGallons = totalGallons + gallons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 2 additional condition in while loop(if with break) to exit from while immediately

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // processing phase
    int miles = 1;
    int gallons = 1;
    int totalMiles = 0;
    int totalGallons = 0;
    float mpg = 0;


    System.out.println("Enter miles or -1 to exit");
    miles = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter gallons");
    gallons = input.nextInt();

    while (miles != -1) {
        System.out.println("Enter miles or -1 to exit");
        miles = input.nextInt();
        if(miles == -1) break;
        System.out.println("Enter gallons or -1 to exit");
        gallons = input.nextInt();
       if(gallons == -1) break;

        totalMiles = totalMiles + miles;
        totalGallons = totalGallons + gallons;


    }
    if (miles == -1) {
        System.out.print("Terminate");
    }
    else{
        mpg = (float) totalMiles / totalGallons;
        System.out.println(mpg);
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Only code is not an answer, explain what you did and how it answers the problem

Comment: I just added 2 additional condition in while loop(if with break) to exit from while, immediately

Comment: Not in comment, edit your post and give text ;) You'll never find a good accepted answer with code only ;)

Comment: Sorry, I new in stackoverflow)

Comment: Don’t be sorry I’m just telling you ;) just learn with the time

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help. Here is the finished and working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int miles = 0;
    int gallons = 0;
    int totalMiles = 0;
    int totalGallon = 0;
    double mpg = 0;
    double totalMpg = 0;

    while(miles != -1){
        System.out.println("Enter mileage or -1 to exit: ");
        miles = input.nextInt();
        if(miles == -1){
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter gallons or -1 to exit: ");
        gallons = input.nextInt();
        mpg = (double) miles / gallons;
        System.out.printf("MPG: %.4f%n", mpg);
        if(gallons == -1){
            break;
        }
        totalMiles = totalMiles + miles;
        totalGallon = totalGallon + gallons;

    }
    if (miles == -1){
        totalMpg = (double) totalMiles / totalGallon;
        System.out.printf("Total used is %.4f%n", totalMpg);
    }


}
```